# Leiningen error: Could not transfer artifact no supported algorithms found

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to use a jar file in my Clojure app. I have never done this before, but reading various articles on the web, I started by doing this, inside of my project:

```
mkdir maven_repository

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=local -DartifactId=nlp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=original-nlp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  -DlocalRepositoryPath=maven_repository
```

And in my project.clj file I have:

```
 [local/nlp "1.0-SNAPSHOT"]
```

but when I run:

```
lein clean
lein uberjar
```

I get this error:

```
Could not transfer artifact local:nlp:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to local (/salesslick/maven_repository/): no supported algorithms found
```

I've checked things like this:

```
lein uberjar

(Retrieving local/nlp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/nlp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom from local)
(Could not transfer artifact local:nlp:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to local   (file:/Users/charlottesville/projects/ollio/salesslick/maven_repository/): no supported algorithms found)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
Uberjar aborting because jar failed: Could not resolve dependencies

cat local/nlp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/nlp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

cat maven_repository/local/nlp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/nlp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>local</groupId>
  <artifactId>nlp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>

lein --version
Leiningen 2.4.1 on Java 1.8.0_25 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://gist.github.com/stuartsierra/3062743

Comment: Thank you. I was working from that.

Comment: What worked for me:     :plugins [
            [lein-localrepo "0.5.3"] ;; install java artifacts locally, even using fake artifactId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining really on time...

I had the same issue and the solution seems to be to actually use maven deploy instead of install.

So the command will look like this:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=local -DartifactId=bar \
  -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=bar.jar \
  -Durl=file:repo
```

You also of course need

```
:repositories {"project" "file:repo"}
```

in your defproject and

```
[local/bar "1.0.0"]
```

in your dependencies.
Note that in -Durl=file:repo file is needed (kind of obvious though) and repo is a folder in the root folder of your repository.

Another way to achieve the same result using purely Leiningen and forgetting about any mvn commands would be to use

```
lein deploy project local/bar 1.0.0 bar.jar
```

instead of the mvn command shown above. This can save you the trouble of actually installing maven on a docker container for example (which can also be tricky depending on the container OS).

All this info is taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/stuartsierra/3062743).

Comment: Thank you, though I wonder how you found a question as old as mine?

Comment: What really worked for me was using the local-repo plugin, which is awesome.

Comment: :plugins [
            [lein-localrepo "0.5.3"] ;; install java artifacts locally, even using fake artifactId
]

Comment: I needed this to work in a Docker container - I wasn't sure how easy would it be to automate the process with lein-localrepo so I went with maven. In the end maven is not needed and this is working with no externel dependency, only a few tweaks in the project file (:repositories + the dependency itself) and a one-liner in the terminal  - lein deploy project xxx.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve this problem myself. After a bit of googling, I got more
confused because there was just too many different solutions. In the end, it
turned out to be *REALLY* easy.

```
Basically, I just used the lein-localrepo plugin. 

1. Add the plugin to my plugins section of profiles.clj i.e.


    {:user 
      {:plugins [[lein-ancient "0.6.10"]
                 [jonase/eastwood "0.2.3"]
                 [lein-kibit "0.1.3"]
                 [lein-bikeshed "0.4.1"]
                 [lein-localrepo "0.5.3"]]
      :dependencies [[slamhound "1.5.5"]]
       :aliases {"slamhound" ["run" "-m" "slam.hound"]}}}
```

2. Ran lein localrepo coords to get the artifact/id stuff

   lein localrepo coords jcifs-1.3.18.jar
3. Add the jar to my .m2 repo

   lein localrepo install jcifs-1.3.18.jar jcifs/jcifs 1.3.18
4. Added the dependency to my project.clj
5. ran lein deps to make sure all looked good
6. In my clj file, added the necessary :import line in the ns header

Worked perfectly!

This does mean that if I want to build this on another machine, the jar file has
to be added to the .m2 on that system. Theoretically, you could specify a
project specific repository directory and then bundle it all up, but I prefer to
keep or my jars in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it is funny to get a question that is 18 months old!

Comment: I should say, that is what I did too. Everyone facing this problem should use the local-repo plugin.